# React's useTransition() stucked in isPending = true when calling api routes from /pages/api folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am having issue with useTransition() that it is being set to true but actually never changes back to false.
I am trying to delete record from MongoDB and once it is finished I would like to refresh React Server Component as explained here:
https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/mutating

Issue is that in this case server component won't get refreshed and Button is stucked with loading text.

```js
'use client'

const DeleteButton = ({ details }) => {
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const router = useRouter();
  
  const handleDelete = async () => {
    await fetch('/api/clients', { method: 'DELETE', body: details._id });
     startTransition(() => {
       console.log('tran started', isPending);
       router.refresh();
     });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // at load isPending = false
    // after start tranisition it is set to false
    // but it never returns back to false 
    console.log('is pending ? ', isPending);
  }, [isPending]);

  return <Button onClick={() => handleDelete()}>{ isPending ? 'Loading' : 'Delete' }</Button>
}
```

This is BE code at /api/clients

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import ClientsCollection from '../../db/collections/clients';
import Client from '../../helpers/interfaces/client';

type Data = {
  name: string;
};
const clientsCollection = new ClientsCollection();

export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<any>) {
  switch (req.method) {
    case 'DELETE': {
      const result = clientsCollection.deleteClientById(req.body);
      res.status(200).json(result);
    }
    default:
      res.status(403);
  }
}
```

Comment: Weirdly I'm not able to reproduce the problem you are facing.

Comment: @yousoumar thanks for confirming this, I thought I have gone insane because it still didn't work even though I have used basic examples. Issue was that I have provided react-redux provided in page.tsx which broke it. After moving Provider to the leaf part (only wrap client component which requires it) it started to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this.

I misunderstood why error did happen, I was basically having useEffect to react on changes from Redux which for some reason blocked setting isPending back to to false.

I did debug it the way that I've commented out current table that was displaying all records and created simple html table without any functionality which helped me identify which code was wrong.